# Fixed Length Flat File Table Algorithms in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, flat-file, fixed-length-record

I am doing simple project for table processing using flat files in c++. I have two type of files to access the table data. 
1) Index File. ( employee.idx )
2) Table File. ( employee.tbl )

In index file, I have table details in the format of tab delimited . i.e.,
Column-name  Column-Type Column-Offset Column-Size

for example, employee.idx

```
ename string 0 10
eage number 10 2
ecity string 12 10
```

In Table file, I have the data in the format of Fixed Length. 
for example, employee.tbl

```
first     25Address0001
second    31Address0002
```

Here I will explain my algorithm what I did in my program.

1) First I have loaded index file data in 2D vector String ( Index Vector ) using fstream.

2) This is my code to load Table File Data into 2D

```
while (fsMain)
{

    if (!getline( fsMain, s )) break;

    string s_str;

    for(size_t i=0;i<idxTable.size();i++)

    {
        int fieldSize=stoi(idxTable[i].at(3));

        string data (s,stoi(idxTable[i].at(2)),fieldSize);

        string tmp=trim_right_inplace(data);

        recordVec.push_back( tmp );

    }

    mainTable.push_back(record);


    recordVec.clear();  

    s="";
}
```

Ok. Now my question is , " Is there any other better way to load the Fixed length data to memory ? ".  I checked this process for 60 tables with 200 Records. It takes nearly 20 Seconds. But I want to load 100 tables with 200  records within one Second. But It takes more time. How can I improve efficiency for this task ?

Comment: I would recommend you store the index in a deserialized (binary) form, in e.g. a structure with the type as an enumeration and the field offset and length as integers. This will be more effective when loading the data as first you don't have to do a second lookup in a vector and also that you don't have to convert the field offset and size to integers in the every time you need to use them.

Comment: Also, if you're after more efficiency, don't use the vectors `at` function, as that performs bounds-checking which of course is more code than the simple array-indexing operator which doesn't have bounds-checking.

Comment: And a general hint: Profile your program! Build with profiling, and run through a profiler to find your bottlenecks, then start working on the worst and go from there.

Comment: And finally, use `emplace_back` if you're using a C++11 capable compiler and library, pre-allocate memory for the vectors when you can, use references if you can when passing arguments and returning arguments (your `trim_right_inplace` function seems like a good candidate for this), and avoid string operations if you can (and look for alternative solutions when you can't).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg. I have more than 10 types of different Index Table.  If I load every table indexes using enumeration and filed offset means , Will it take more memory ? and I want to change the column details whenever I want. So that only, I have those data as Table Driven.

Comment: You seem to be using vectors of `std::string`, each `std::string` might use a pointer and a size, on a 64-bit machine they are likely 8 bytes each, plus the actual string data of course. For the string `"10"` that's 18 (or 19 if it stores the terminator, which it likely does) bytes. An `int` is only 4 bytes, and unless you have extremely large fields you could get away with a `uint16_t` (two bytes) or maybe even a `uint8_t` (one byte). And the basic types used by the data will not be that different? And worst case `enum` is equivalent to `int` (four bytes).